# Django object does not exist

Tags: python, django

I have the following view in my views.py:

```
def MoveSucessfulEntries(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        objectsToBeDeleted = request.POST['imagesToBeRemoved']
        for objects in objectsToBeDeleted:
            print objects
            image = Image.objects.get(id=objects)
            SucessfulImage(emailAddress=image.emailAddress, image=image.image, caption=image.caption).save()
        return render_to_response('images/selectedSucessful.html')
    else:   
        images = Image.objects.all()
        return render_to_response('images/deleteUnsucessfulEntries.html', {'images': images})
```

`imagesToBeRemoved` are checkboxes on the HTML page that have the IDs of the images in the database which is generated like so:

```
<form method="POST" action="/image/selectSucessful">
    {% if images %}
        {% for image in images %}
            <input type="checkbox" name="imagesToBeRemoved" value="{{image.id}}" /> <image src="../media/{{image.image}}"> <br>
        {%endfor%}
        <input type="submit" value="Select" />
    {% else %}
        <p>No images are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

So I know that the ids returned from the form are in the database yet I keep getting the error object does not exist. Whats wrong with my code?

The stack trace says that the error is happening on:

```
image = Image.objects.get(id=objects)
```

Comment: What object doesn't exist? What line is the error referring to?

Comment: it may be that the value of the checkbox is a string and the id i imagine is an int/long try removing the quotes from the `value="foo"` pretty sure that still valid html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you're getting a string with

```
objectsToBeDeleted = request.POST['imagesToBeRemoved']
```

Since you're POSTing multiple data what you want is:

```
objectsToBeDeleted = request.POST.getlist('imagesToBeRemoved')
```

Strings are iterable so you iterate over each of the digits, that is, if you want to delete an item with an id of 345, it'll actually try to delete the items with ids of 3, 4, and 5.